# ffmpeg: alpha merge with audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I am alpha merging two videos for iOS/Apple devices (mov), the color.mp4 has audio, while alpha.mp4 has not. The end result has no audio ouput. What is the proper flag to grab audio from color.mp4 onto the output?

```
 ffmpeg -y -i color.mp4 -i alpha.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=320x568 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=320:568,setsar=1:1,split[vs][alpha];[0:v][vs]alphamerge[vt];[2:v][vt]overlay=shortest=1[rgb];[rgb][alpha]alphamerge" -shortest -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -alpha_quality 0.75 -vtag hvc1 -pix_fmt yuva420p -an output.mov
```

Answer (score 0):

`-an` disables audio mapping. Remove it. Add `-c:a copy` if you wish to avoid re-encoding the audio.